# Record stream video by Azure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I need to record a stream video (say I have an url) and save the last N minutes of it to Azure?

My guess is that I need to use Azure media service for that. 
I've already created an Azure media service account.

Could anybody give me a hint where to start from.

**Update:**

1. I'd prefer to use C#
2. Stream can be from blob:http://ipcamlive.com/a5fe3312-2a33-4b53-8b83-42af7928abb0 or from any web camera. Currently I'm not sure about the video format

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really given much info on what type of video, what language you'll use so probably best to start with [Azure Media Services documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/)

Here you can find a [tutorial on encoding from HTTPS source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-dotnet-quickstart) using .NET

If you can give more info on what you're looking to do, you'll likely get better hints; right now this smells like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Thank you. I'd prefer to use C# (python is possible is well). Say I want to save youtube streams.

Comment: No, I'd prefer C# much

Comment: Saving YouTube streams has legal and copyright implications.  Suggest you consult someone on that first.

Comment: Why do you want to save youtube streams to Azure, they're already saved in YouTube. This smells like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @LouO.I talked about youtube as an example. Actually it will be an IP camera.